# MouseImp alternative on Linux (drag and scroll)?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, mouse, browser

is there a tool that enables you to scroll by dragging the mouse with the right button pressed. I was using an app called "MouseImp" on Windows many years ago. The tool was quite handy, since you were able to scroll much faster than with the mouse-wheel e.g. on large pages. Moreover you were able to scroll horizontally as well.

This all was possible by just keeping the right mouse-button pressed anywhere on a window and dragging the pointer up, down etc.

The software became open-source a few years ago but AFAIK there has not been a linux port.

Best,
YSN

Comment: I don't think that there's an overall solution, since most applications already have such a functionality (Firefox f.e. by clicking with the Middle-Mouse-Button). For what applications would you need it?

Comment: Hi, I'd need it globally (for different browsers, applications, and nautilus). Mouseimp was far more efficient than scrolling with the mouse-wheel - anybody who has ever used it knows ;-)

Comment: BTW, clicking the mouse button and scrolling by dragging the mouse pointer away, e.g. in Firefox, is not what I meant. Mouseimp works in a different way - you keep the button pressed while dragging. This way you have more control, like dragging the scrollbar, but without having to aim at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the tool that pefectly works! It is even better than MoueImp on Windows has been, and works globally, anywhere you have a scrollbar.

It is called **Gpointing** and can be installed from the Ubuntu Software-Center or by typing

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

in a terminal.

You need to start the tool, activate mouse-wheel-emulation and choose your desired mouse button (right button is number 3 in my case).

The tool seems to be great for touchpad-users as well, since it allows you to customize so many things, like scrolling with circular movement on the touchpad (very handy on large pages).

Answer (score 0):

For GNU/Linux here is not a tool that enables you to scroll by dragging the mouse with the right button pressed --as far as I know.