# alternative to mousewheel

Tags: scrolling, mouse-wheel

I am getting progressively worse hand pain from using the mousewheel.  I have two questions:

1) How can I disable the mousewheel?  I realize tape, glue, pointy spikes poking up could work, but is there a less drastic software solution?

2) On windows you can hold a button then scroll using the mouse to drag the window.  This seems it could be a better option.

Update: I have resorted to tape (1) and found the gpointing-device-settings tools (2) from this answer: [MouseImp alternative on Linux (drag and scroll)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8000/mouseimp-alternative-on-linux-drag-and-scroll)

Comment: I saw this today and it seems perfect: https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/flow-the-world-s-most-magical-controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [MouseImp alternative on Linux (drag and scroll)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8000/mouseimp-alternative-on-linux-drag-and-scroll)

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, it's better to post it as an answer to your question and accept it as answer. This way, it is more clear for people that your question is answered.

Comment: @Galgalesh gpointing-device-settings doesn't work with Gtk3 any more. I contacted one of the developers, who responded that the project was discontinued.

Comment: @Galgalesh - I don't have a nice solution to disable it.  tape is working though.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I am using a rollermouse:red.  It cured my middle finger pain (scrollwheel induced) but it has a scrollwheel that you use with your thumb.  That is, until you tape it.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the mouse wheel, type `xinput` into the Terminal and find the device name of your mouse (mine was "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b").

You can test this by typing `xinput --disable "Your Mouse Name"` and checking whether the mouse responds. To reenable the mouse, type `xinput --enable "Your Mouse Name"`.

Type `xinput set-button-map "Your Mouse Name" 1 0 3 0 0 6 7 8 9`

Replacing 2, 4, and 5 with zeroes will disable middle click and scroll up/down, respectively.

You can add this to Startup Applications.

Comment: that works - thanks rob!  i had actually looked at this earlier but didn't figure out the button numbers (by looking at `xev`).  *however* it also disables the gpointing override (2).